# Can't UV unwrap a simple bag

Tags: modeling, uv, uv-image-editor

Hi I'm new to blender world. I have the following model which I'm trying to UV Unwrapping with Cylinder Protection.

[image]

I think I've placed my seems correctly but I get following UV Image.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You will need a seam running the length of it vertically somewhere (I suggest one of the sides)

Comment: Christopher is right. Also I would suggest you use the 'unwrap' instead of the cylinder projection. Since the bag seems kinda 'flattened' and not very cylindrical, the cylinder projection will end up creating more distortion.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Thanks for the reply. I've included a seem on one of the sides. Here the UV Image https://i.imgur.com/DUytxog.png What do you think?

Comment: It looks a lot better, but those diagonals should probably be dealt with. If you need to find "offending faces" you can enable _UV Sync Selection_ (button is in top left of UV editor - looks like 2 arrows pointing in opposite directions on an angle) - when you are in face select mode, you can select a face on the UV map and see where it corresponds on your mesh. It can make seam placement easier to visualize in many situations.

Comment: You don't need all the horizontal seams you created. Just to one seam on the top and one on the bottom, and a vertical one on the side, then press U and "unwrap". it will open the bag neatly and in only one UV island.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati Thanks for the reply. To be honest I don't know what I'm doing wrong. UV Image with 3 seems https://i.imgur.com/t6Xcs3v.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mark seams on top and bottom and a vertical seam on the side:

[image]

[image]

Then go to UV editing and select all faces, then press U and "Unwrap". Result:

[image]

Comment: You can also use the cylinder projection, it results in straighter edges in the UVs, but it also distorts the proportions of the faces in relation to each other (the side faces end up wider and front and back faces end up narrower in relation to each other). Just make sure to be in front orthographic view when you do the cylinder projection.

Comment: I think I've done with cylinder projection it https://i.imgur.com/xwSnyv8.png. For some reason it doesn't work with "Unwrap". Thank you so much!

Comment: Looks great. Glad to help!